# Invoke google cloud http function when message publish on a pub sub

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, .net-core, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have already written the code for google cloud http function however now I also wants to trigger the same function when the message published on pubsub.

So how do I invoke same cloud function from Http and ICloundEventFunction(fron pubsub)?

Comment: Your `Cloud Function` reads data from `Pub Sub` ?

Comment: Yes I will read a message from Pub Sub as input to the cloud function for further processing the logic

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 2nd generation Cloud Function and create HTTP and PubSub triggers in one Cloud Function.

You can find details about it from this link: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-2nd-generation-now-generally-available

Comment: Could you please help me with any google cloud function link or a article?

Comment: I just edited my comment and shared a link where you can find details.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly trigger a Cloud function on push mode with a Pub Sub topic :

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub

This link explains well how to deploy a Cloud Function that listen a topic :

```
gcloud functions deploy YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME \
--trigger-topic=YOUR_PUBSUB_TOPIC \
[--retry] \
...
```

The cloud function is triggered when a message is published on the topic.

In Cloud Functions (2nd gen), Pub/Sub triggers are implemented as a particular type of Eventarc trigger.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/eventarc